# How to make dynamic font colors in css

Tags: html, css, fonts, colors

I'm designing a website and I want the color of my text to change based on the position of the text on the screen. Specifically, I wanted the text to start darker at the bottom, and change to a lighter color gradually as you scroll up.

I'm not sure how to do this, but I need advice on an idea I had. My idea is to somehow make the text transparent, as well as the portion of the containing div covered by said text, and then make a fixed background image which would just be a gradient image (light on top, dark on bottom). If this is the correct approach, how would I do this?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

The difference here is that we use RGBA values instead of opacity. RGBA let us  set a color AND change the opacity using its fourth parameter.

Read more about gradients here:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
    // Get scroll position
    var scroll = this.scrollY;
    // Get possible scroll maximum
    var maxscroll = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    // Make percentage thing (so we get a number from 0 to 1)
    var percentage = 1 - scroll / maxscroll;
    // Set percentage as opacity for bottom of div using RGBA values (which let us use percentages of opacity)
    document.getElementById("container").style="background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(255,250,0,1),rgba(255,0,0,"+percentage+"))";
    
});
```

```css
body{
/*SO relevant*/
background:#121212;
font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:white;
}
#container{
/*SO relevant*/
font-size:30px;
display:inline-block;
padding:5px;
font-weight:bold;
/*Center the container*/
position:fixed;
top:40%;
left:35%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
Gradient box
</div>
Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>Some text to enable scrolling...<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Tho, theres still the bug with the scroll position not reaching the bottom of the document (thats why you dont get opacity=0 when you scroll all the way down). Keep in mind that if you apply this function to a div and that you can scroll that div out of view that wont be a problem anymore.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This really helps thanks! Instead of changing opacity, what I want it to do is change color. So if I have a color gradient (from top to bottom), I want the text color to reflect the corresponding percentage from the top of the gradient. How would I get the color values of the gradient image file from javascript? Sorry if my question is unclear.